# Can I do getCursor() on Google script bounded on google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm playing with google script. I want to execute getCursor() on the google script that's bounded to a google spreadsheet, but it seems it doesn't work. I can successfully open the google docs by DocumentApp.openbyId() on my google spreadsheet script, but getCursor() returns null although both google docs and google spreadsheet files are owned by me. Is it just impossible? or is there any way to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, you cannot use `getCursor` in a Sheet because it does not exist.

[`getCursor()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getcursor) is a method for the `Document` class from the Document Service.

No such method exists in Spreadsheet Service.

As an alternative, have you tried [`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveRange())?